# Get by class and sort numerically in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, pagination

I know how to use .sort() in javascript.

My question is how can i sort and create pagination in javascript if i have the following example.

```
<div class='rated'>5</div>
<div class='rated'>10</div>
<div class='rated'>6</div>
<div class='rated'>8</div>
<div class='rated'>5</div>
```

How can i get all the divs by class and sort them based on rating, and also display only two results per page.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is a start, then do your `sort()` - then break them up by 2.

Comment: Get the collection of `divs` `document.getElementsByClassName` -- get the content of each `div` and add to an array.  Ask a specific question if you need help with that one.  Sort the array .. there is a nice `sort` method you can use.  Then, update the contents of the first two `divs` and hide/remove the rest.

Comment: thanks tymeJV getElementsByClassName i do know but how to access the values inside and pagination?